# Import error when deploying Flask application to Kubernetes (GCP)

Tags: python, flask, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm new to Kubernetes, so assume i don't know anything about deploying applications in it.

I have a Flask application and i'm trying to deploy from Azure Pipelines to GCP Kubernetes Cluster. I've already set up all the environment but, when i launch a new Release (from Azure Pipelines), i receive import errors at the GCP Kubernetes Logs screen, regarding the libraries i am using in my application. The main one that appears is:

`ImportError: cannot import name 'anonymous_user_required' from 'flask_security'`

Which is strange, since i have set up a Virtual Environment, with all the packages at `requirements.txt` on my local machine and everything runs smoothly.

Below is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7

ENV APP_HOME /app
ENV PORT 5000

WORKDIR $APP_HOME

COPY . $APP_HOME

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

And my deployment.yaml:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
  selector:
    app: app
  type: NodePort

---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: app
    servicePort: 80
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: app
        image: APP_IMAGE
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
        livenessProbe:      # Used by deployment controller
          httpGet:
            path: /
            port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 5
        readinessProbe:     # Used by Ingress/GCLB
          httpGet:
            path: /
            port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: 3
          periodSeconds: 5
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 1024Mi
          requests:
            memory: 768Mi
```

The APP_IMAGE is being set on my azure-pipelines.yml:

```yaml
steps:
- task: CmdLine@1
  displayName: 'Lock image version in deployment.yaml'
  inputs:
    filename: /bin/bash
    arguments: '-c "awk ''{gsub(\"APP_IMAGE\", \"gcr.io/$(DockerImageName):$(Build.BuildId)\", $0); print}'' deployment.yaml > $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/deployment.yaml"'
```

I followed Google Tutorial to deploy the application to a Kubernetes Cluster. The pipeline is working fine, it's publishing the Docker Image in the Google Container Registry and the Release from Azure is generating logs at the GCP Kubernetes screen.

Am i missing something at the deployment.yaml file? There is some extra configuration i have to do in GCP Kubernetes to make it work?

Comment: Out of date Flask versions in your requirements.txt???

Comment: No, everything is up to date. Like i said, i`ve been running local, using the requirements.txt in my venv and it's ok.

Comment: 1) Post your requirements.txt in your question. 2) Test the container at your desktop under Docker. 3) Verify that the version of the Flask libraries are the same inside the container.